# Register 32 bit COM dll in 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, windows, com, 64-bit, regsvr32

I have a 32 bit COM dll (generated using VC++)

I want to use the dll in my C# / .NET project.

I copied the dll to my DEV 64 bit win 7 machine and executed the following command in command prompt

```
C:\windows\SYSWOW64\regsvr32 xyz.dll
```

It was successfully imported. Now I am able to use the dll in my C# project. Everything works fine.

Now I want to deploy the application to a Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bit) machine.

I am getting an error while registering the COM dll as I did in Win 7 machine

Error :

> The module "xyz.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary stored at
>   the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary
>   or dependant .DLL files. The specified module could not be found.

But I copied the dll into the `SYSWOW64` folder

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Does the DLL have dependencies?  It could be it works on your machine because you have visual studio (or some other software)  installed that fulfills the dependencies of that dll.

Comment: it does not have a dependencies. i have visual studio in 2008 server R2 as well

Comment: You wrote it in VC++? It does have at least one dependency: did you install the **32-bit** Visual C++ runtime library on the server?

Comment: Well, ok. If you installed VS on the server (which I wouldn't recommend) then you should have the x86 runtime already. Is it the correct patch level/service pack though? My standard troubleshooting here is to use depends.exe to see if there is a dependency it can't find. Also, is the C# program running as 64-bit? You might want to compile it as 32-bit instead of "anycpu" to make sure it doesn't try to run as 64-bit.

Comment: I did not write the VC++ code, its developed by 3rd party but i have the solution and compiled the VC++ project in 32 bit machine. Adn then used the DLL in my Win 7 64 bit machine by doing regsvr32. Everything just works fine. But getting the problem in win 2008 server 64 bit

Comment: EuroMicelli , I ran process monitor for regsvr32 and found that it has a dependecy on open ssl and have installed that. Everything works just fine. thanks for your advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved it by investigating the DLL dependencies using Process Monitor.
I found that it had dependency so i have installed the dependency then everything started to work